# WebLogic installation errors - Unable to access the selected application

Tags: grails, weblogic, war

Installing an app in the WebLogic console raises the following errors:

Messages

```
Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Message icon - Error Apps tool failure: Check nested exception for details
Message icon - Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Has anyone else seen these errors?

Comment: What does the admin server log say in `<your domain>/servers/<admin server>/logs`? The errors in the console only hint at the real problem. My guess is the log has a better description of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by re-creating the data sources. Somehow existing data sources are screwed up. Once I re-created the data sources... my problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in the end the data sources in some maven jars that I had changed were wrong, the problem was from me that I took a maven jar from another application that I had and I forgot to change the data sources inside, but because it was a jar it didn't I was hit by the problem right away on weblogic 12.1.1 version, when I ran it with weblogic 12.1.3 on my console it brought up the data sources connecting and that's how I figured out the problem, then just watch the data sources